# Volusion: Images not shown on front end

Tags: php, image, ftp, volusion

I have uploaded my all images to the folder  **vspfiles/photos** through FTP in Volusion but they are not shown on front end. I have already added the products to Volusion but it did not assign images to the relative products.

**Relative products means:** Volusion provide a facility that rename your image to the product-code so Volusion will assign that image to the product that has match with product-code.

I followed the method from the below link:

[Adding images to your Volusion store products](http://adxmedia.com/articles/adding-images-to-your-volusion-store-products/)

Any one have an idea about this please help me.

Comment: did you checked the image uploaded in the target folder?? or accessed the images through url??

Comment: @Asif Rao yes bro I have checked images through url like this:

http://tebkq.mvlce.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/photos/RSP002-2T.jpg